# How to remove image margins when plotting and exporting square image with R?

Tags: r, image, tiff

I'm trying to plot a square TIFF image (1024 x 1024), but it displays it as a vertically stretched rectangle. I've tried adjusting margins in `plotRGB` and utilizing `par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))`, but I can't get the plot and output to be a square even though R recognizes the raster as a square.

Does anyone have any advice on how to simply fix this issue? I've attached two images, one of the original image and one of the image when plotted/exported in R. The goal of my program is to use `histmatch` solely to adjust the saturation of the source image to that of a matching reference image. The exported image thus cannot be vertically stretched, and must have no margin.

[Screenshot of original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fRhr.jpg)

[R display and export of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lT8L9.jpg)

Comment: Look at ?par. I think you will find an “asp” parameter described. If it’s not ther then it’s perhaps in the ?plot.default page.

Comment: Probably `asp=1` is the issue, but you have provided no data, no code.

Comment: `asp=0` fixed it, thank you!!!